Exterior Peeling Paint Removal
What would be the best way to remove this paint from my houses exterior? I tried all manners of paint removing chemicals and none worked (citristrip, kleanstrip premium, kleanstrip mineral spirits). Am I doomed to have to sand my entire home (it's like this over the entire exterior in patches all over).


Prep work is 90% of a good, long lasting paint job.  This is usually a very good cleaning and removing all loose paint.  Sanding should be left for smoothing, but scraping/wire brush might be needed for tough paint.  Are you using paint strippers made for exterior paint?  Read instructions.

All the strippers I used claimed to be able to remove any paint from any surface if left to sit for 15 minutes. While there was a little removal, there was none of the "15 layers guaranteed" that they claimed.

I think you'll need to augment with mechanical methods—either a wire brush type machine or a pressure washer.
